# How do I store the right value in $_SESSION depending on which button the user clicks on?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have the following code:

```
while ($content = mysql_fetch_array($content2)){  
    echo $content[0];  
    session_start();  
    $_SESSION['content'] = $content[0];  
    ?>  
    <br />    
    <a href="edit.php"> Edit post. </a>  
    <br /> <br />  
    <?php  
}
```

It fetches and displays all posts from a blog system database, and you can click on "Edit." below each post. What I want to do is pass the content of that post to my edit.php script.
  The problem is, whichever "Edit" button I click on, this will always pass the content of my last post, not the content of the post above that "Edit" button.
 Now, I can see why that might be: The whole loop will be executed before I click on any button, and the value stored in $_SESSION['content'] will always be the value from the loop's last iteration. Am I right?

Maybe I shouldn't be using SESSION. Is there a better approach? How can I pass the "right" value of $content[0] to my edit.php script?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Why don't you pass the contentId for the database entry and get the information on the edit page or use $_GET with the contentId edit.php?contentId=125

Comment: @Truth: Thanks. To be honest, I just need a quick fix right now, but I will look at the right way to do it.

Comment: @Marcio: Yes, each post has a unique id, but I don't know how to pass it. Maybe what GrayB said is an explanation of that, but I'm not sure I get it.

Comment: I wrote an explanation in my answer, what is your database query? I can change my answer to help you understand it better,

Comment: I have to go now, but I'll try out the things that you and the others told me a bit later, and then upvote/accept answer(s), depending on the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the edit button is always getting the last post is because you are overriding the content variable in the session on each loop.

I am not sure what information you are getting from the database, but you should have a unique  ID in the database for each post which you grab in the array as well.  If this does not exists, I would **strongly** recommend making a change in your table as it will simplify your process.

```
while ($content = mysql_fetch_assoc($content2))
{  
    echo $content['postText'] . "<br />";  
    echo '<a href="edit.php?postId=' . $content['postId'] . '"> Edit post. </a><br /><br />';  
}
```

You will then have to set up the edit page to grab the id `$_GET['postId']` and grab the proper content from the database.

Comment: Thanks, I think that'll fix it. Yes, I realised I was overriding the content, but couldn't figure out how to avoid that. I do have a unique ID in my database, but wasn't aware of that "edit.php?postId=" thing.

Comment: I hope it helps, I changed my answer to use mysql_fetch_assoc so you can use the field names instead of 0,1. You should listen to Truth advice about changing the database PDO or MySQLi. Good luck and post if you need any further assistants

Answer (score 1):

You code must be improved, your logic isn't good. First of all, you don't need to use a session var, one alternative to do this is passing the post ID using a GET argument, something like this:

```
while ( $content = mysql_fetch_array($content2) )
{  
    $post_content = $content[0];
    $post_id      = $content[1];

    echo $post_content . '<br /> <a href="edit.php?postId=' . $post_id . '"> Edit post. </a> <br /> <br />';
}
```

Then, in `edit.php` you will retrieve the `$_GET['postId']` and load the post content to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

This would be your best bet if you are ready to go for GET commands. See the code below :

```
$content = mysql_fetch_array($content2);
foreach($content as $key => $val) {
echo "<a href=edit.php?id=$val['id']>$val['name']</a>";
}
```

Just a quick fix.

Replace $val['id'] with the column name of uniqueID and $val['name'] with the column name of the post.